# What is the recommended way of setting variable in macro definition

Tags: makefile

I define a macro in gmake to set a variable before calling the underlying function, and reset it afterwards:

```
define InstallWithPermission
    $(eval ORIG_INSTALL_FILE_MODE = $(INSTALL_FILE_MODE))
    $(eval INSTALL_FILE_MODE = $(1))
    $(InstallFile)
    $(eval INSTALL_FILE_MODE = $(ORIG_INSTALL_FILE_MODE))
    $(eval ORIG_INSTALL_FILE_MODE = )
endef
```

Here the $(InstallFile) will call *install* command with INSTALL_FILE_MODE as its file mode.

- In order to set variables in a macro definition, I use *eval* function
- In order to make sure ORIG_INSTALL_FILE_MODE is *local*, I reset it to empty at the end of the maro

Should this the right way to manipulate "local variables" inside a macro definition?

Thanks.

Comment: Seems we can't define a make variable directly inside a macro, unless you use $(shell), rather than $(call) to call the macro, in which case that becomes a shell variable, not a make variable

Answer (score 1):

There is a cleaner way to do what you're trying. The trick is to keep careful track of expansions, and in this case use simply expanded variables to avoid a circular definition:

```
define InstallWithPermission
  ORIG_INSTALL_FILE_MODE := $(INSTALL_FILE_MODE)
  INSTALL_FILE_MODE := $(1)
  $$(InstallFile)
  INSTALL_FILE_MODE := $$(ORIG_INSTALL_FILE_MODE)
endef
```

But I'd advise you to do without these local variables entirely, and have `InstallFile` accept an argument.

Comment: There is a error when call this macro: `gmake: ORIG_INSTALL_FILE_MOD: Command not found`, is this a valid syntax to assign a variable directly in a macro definition?